# What "person" is Ebony Maw referring to?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* (2018), Ebony Maw says to Doctor Strange, who wears necklace with Time Stone on it:

> In all the time I've served Thanos...I have never failed him. If I
>   were to reach our rendezvous on Titan...with the Time Stone still
>   attached to your vaguely irritating **person**... there would be judgment.

What "person" is Ebony Maw referring to?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker but it seems clear to me that he is referring to Doctor Strange. Translation: "If I go back to Thanos while you still have the Time Stone (in the necklace), I will have problems".

Comment: In this case "person" is short for "[personage"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/personage).

Comment: Answer in answers, please, not in comments.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/person), "Person" can refer to:

> A human being regarded as an individual.
>
> An individual characterized by a preference or liking for a specified thing.
>
> An individual's body.

Thus, that is **simply his manner of speech** when talking about Doctor Strange.

Answer (score 10):

**Ebony Maw is an orator. The "person" he is referring to is no less than the body of Doctor Strange. His language is unnecessarily ornate describing Doctor Strange as if he was a non-entity.**

The translation would be: "If I were to return to Thanos with the Time Stone still on your body, not available for his immediate use, I would be punished. No one wants this."